# Как сгенерировать QR Code и сохранить на жестком диске?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qrcode

Как сгенерировать QR Code из строчки текста и сохранить его в виде картинки (например, PNG) на жестком диске?

Comment: Дополните вопрос более конкретным пояснением вашей задачи. Добавте также фрагмент коде, где у вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: @0xdb, представьте что я новичек и не умею пользоваться гуглом, а про QR Code был наслышан и с такими знаниями пошел на стековерфлоу чтобы задать вопрос :) Ответ уже ниже дал, это вопрос из серии  "[делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)"

Comment: Только ЗА. Это и имел в виду под - "более конкретным пояснением вашей задачи".  Из очереди проверок ответов не видно. Написали бы - "авторский ответ следует",  или что-то типа того.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо за пояснение и подсказку :)

Comment: Убрал примечание, т.к. оно ничуть не уточняет вопрос. А вопрос могут заслуженно закрыть - т.к. он слишком общий. Вы даже не уточняете что именно вы хотите сохранить на ЖД.

Comment: @Kromster, думал что контекст будет понятен :) Да и вопроса по теме  `QR Code` в питоне нет еще. Что я собираюсь исправить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания `QR Code` можно использовать замечательный модуль [qrcode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode) ([github](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode))

```
import io

# pip install qrcode
import qrcode


text = 'Hello World!'
img = qrcode.make(text)

# Если нужно сохранить в памяти
io_data = io.BytesIO()
img.save(io_data, 'png')
data = io_data.getvalue()
print(data)

# Если нужно сохранить в файле (через нативный метод save)
img.save('qr_code_1.png')

# Если нужно сохранить в файле (используя open и сохраненный байтовый массив)
with open('qr_code_2.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Консоль:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01"\x00\x00\x01"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00u\xc5\xe2\x1b\x00\x00\x01zIDATx\x9c\xed\x99K\x8e\x830\x10D_\x0fH\xb347\x98\xa3\x98\xa3\xc3Qr\x03\xbc\x8cDT\xb30\xbfL\x16\x93\x8d\x03\x82\xf6\n\xd0\x93(5\xed\xa6(L\xfc\xbf\xfa\xaf7 p\xca)\xa7\x9cr\xea\xe8\x94M\xab\x86\xde\xcc \xcdW\xda]u]\x82\x8a\x92\xa4\x01\x88C%k\xa9$Iz\xa6>\xaf\xeb\x12T\x9az\xdc\xdap7u@\xde\x06{\xeb\xba\x18U\xbd\xda\xceC\xe8\xba\x00\x95\x96)\xff\xa9;^\x95\x9a\xc7J\x10\x90\x80\xbe\xa9F\x03\xd8v\xffQ\xd5\x9f\x82\xea\xcd\xcc\xac\x01\xe2\x00\xc0#\xdb\x9c\xbdu\x9d\x9a\xca}\xbf\xe9\xf1\xbe\xc1\xa6m\xb0\xa7\xae\xebP\xd6\xa6\xc9\xdf\xab\xa3\xd2\xec\xef\xdd\xe7\x14\xa5\xc8>>[{\x8dl]=\x95\xb2\xf1\xef\x8e\xaa\xfe\x0c\x94\xd9\xcf\x08\xa4o\x01\x0fSG%u\xf9hO]\xe7\xa6\xa6F\x8f\x9aW.{\x90`\xfe\xb8\xf5\xbe/C\xb1\xad\xf8\xfcY\x95O\xd7\x87\xe2\xb5/B\xa1\xe7\x05a\xa9xX\xf6\xc2Q\xd5\x9f\x81Zs\xcci\xc0\xa7\x1a\xe2\xcd\xfd}Q\xeai\xde\x0fK\x94\x13\xc6\xcd\xe0\xf1\xbe/K\xad)N\x90\x88\xb7\x1a\xa2\xee\x9e\xdf\x97\xa4\xea\x97+\xa9\x1e\xd57`\x84\xc1\xf3\xfb\x92\xd4k\xed\xc3\x80E=j\x91\xeaq7]W\xa2\x82\xa4\x0e\xa6wm\xdfT\xca\xd1\xda\xde\xba\xceL\xbd\x84\x08@\xfeq\xb8F\x0c\xfe\xae-C\xfd\xcd1\xe7\xa3\x11m\xfe`\x1dU\xbdSN9\xe5\x94S\xefR\xbf\xa2\xe9\xe7\x8c\x86\xfe\n\xde\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]